# UTF-8 Character Count

Tags: c, utf-8

I'm programming something that counts the number of UTF-8 characters in a file.  I've already written the base code but now, I'm stuck in the part where the characters are supposed to be counted.  So far, these are what I have:

What's inside the text file:

```
黄埔炒蛋
你好
こんにちは
여보세요
```

What I've coded so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef unsigned char BYTE;

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    FILE *file = fopen("file.txt", "r");
    if (!file)
    {
        printf("Could not open file.\n");
        return 1;
    }
    int count = 0;

    while(1)
    {
        BYTE b;
        fread(&b, 1, 1, file);
        if (feof(file))
        {
            break;
        }
        count++;
    }
    printf("Number of characters: %i\n", count);

    fclose(file);

    return 0;
}
```

My question is, how would I code the part where the UTF-8 characters are being counted?  I tried to look for inspirations in GitHub and YouTube but I haven't found anything that works well with my code yet.

Edit: Originally, this code prints that the text file has 48 characters.  But considering UTF-8, it should only be 18 characters.

Comment: You could follow the [encoding rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Encoding). If multibyte, continue to read the right number of bytes to satisfy the character encoding.

Comment: Do you want to verify the UTF-8 encoding as well or do you want to assume that the data is valid UTF-8?

Comment: I want to assume that the data is valid UTF-8.

Comment: `fread(&b, 1, 1, file);
        if (feof(file))` - fun fact, if there's an error while reading the file, your code will endlessly loop. Forget `feof` exists! Check return value of the functions, of `fread`,  to determine if your operation succeeded. `if (fread(&b, 1, 1, file) != 1) { break; }`

Comment: Pedantic mode: you are counting the Unicode codepoints (control code points are not always "Unicode Characters", e.g. new line), and it is disputable if a variant count as one or two characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Encoding

Each UTF-8 sequence contains one starting byte and zero or more extra bytes.
Extra bytes always start with bits `10` and first byte never starts with that sequence.
You can use that information to count only first byte in each UTF-8 sequence.

```
    if((b&0xC0) != 0x80) {
        count++;
    }
```

Keep in mind this will break, if file contains invalid UTF-8 sequences.
Also, "UTF-8 characters" might mean different things. For example "" will be counted as two characters by this method.

Comment: Just finished reading the content in the link you've attached.  However, I'm quite confused as to how will I apply those things in my code.

Comment: @thepajama For a specific question create a new one here on StackOverflow. Point the exact point that starts your confusion and point out which things you understood so far.

Answer (score 1):

In C, as in C++, there is no ready-made solution for counting UTF-8 characters. You can convert UTF-8 to UTF-16 using *mbstowcs* and use the *wcslen* function, but this is not the best way for performance (especially if you only need to count the number of characters and nothing else).

I think a good answer to your question is here: [counting unicode characters in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3586973/10863380).

Еxample from answer on link:

```c
for (p; *p != 0; ++p)
    count += ((*p & 0xc0) != 0x80);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could look into the specs: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3629.

Chapter 3 has this table in it:

```
   Char. number range  |        UTF-8 octet sequence
      (hexadecimal)    |              (binary)
   --------------------+---------------------------------------------
   0000 0000-0000 007F | 0xxxxxxx
   0000 0080-0000 07FF | 110xxxxx 10xxxxxx
   0000 0800-0000 FFFF | 1110xxxx 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx
   0001 0000-0010 FFFF | 11110xxx 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx
```

You could inspect the bytes and build the unicode characters.

A different point is, whether you would count a base character and its accent (combining mark cf. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_character) as one or as several characters.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple options you may take:

- you may depend on your system implementation of wide encoding and multibyte encoding

  - you may read the file as a wide stream and just count the bytes, depend on the system to do UTF-8 multibyte string to wide string conversion on it's own (see `main1` below)
  - you may read the file as bytes and convert the multibyte string into a wide string and count bytes (see `main2` below)
- You may use an external library that operates on UTF-8 strings and count the unicode characters (see `main3` below that uses `libunistring`)
- Or roll your own `utf8_strlen`-ish solution that will work on specific UTF-8 string property and check the bytes yourself, as showed in other answers.

Here is an example program that has to be compiled with `-lunistring` under linux with rudimentary error checking with `assert`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void main1()
{
    // read the file as wide characters
    const char *l = setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_US.UTF-8");
    assert(l);
    FILE *file = fopen("file.txt", "r");
    assert(file);
    int count = 0;
    while(fgetwc(file) != WEOF) {
        count++;
    }
    fclose(file);
    printf("Number of characters: %i\n", count);
}

// just a helper function cause i'm lazy
char *file_to_buf(const char *filename, size_t *strlen) {
    FILE *file = fopen(filename, "r");
    assert(file);
    size_t n = 0;
    char *ret = malloc(1);
    assert(ret);
    for (int c; (c = fgetc(file)) != EOF;) {
        ret = realloc(ret, n + 2);
        assert(ret);
        ret[n++] = c;
    }
    ret[n] = '\0';
    *strlen = n;
    fclose(file);
    return ret;
}

void main2() {
    const char *l = setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_US.UTF-8");
    assert(l);
    size_t strlen = 0;
    char *str = file_to_buf("file.txt", &strlen);
    assert(str);
    // convert multibye string to wide string
    // assuming multibytes are in UTF-8
    // this may also be done in a streaming fashion when reading byte by byte from a file
    // and calling with `mbtowc` and checking errno for EILSEQ and managing some buffer
    mbstate_t ps = {0};
    const char *tmp = str;
    size_t count = mbsrtowcs(NULL, &tmp, 0, &ps);
    assert(count != (size_t)-1);
    printf("Number of characters: %zu\n", count);
    free(str);
}

#include <unistr.h> // u8_mbsnlen from libunistring

void main3() {
    size_t strlen = 0;
    char *str = file_to_buf("file.txt", &strlen);
    assert(str);
    // for simplicity I am assuming uint8_t is equal to unisgned char
    size_t count = u8_mbsnlen((const uint8_t *)str, strlen);
    printf("Number of characters: %zu\n", count);
    free(str);
}

int main() {
    main1();
    main2();
    main3();
}
```